# How to open 3 file with a if function

Tags: c

Hi I'm trying to add a 3th file to the code below but i have no idea on how to do this.

original code:

```
char *fileOpen1;
char *fileOpen2;
while(fgets(line, 50, fr) != NULL)
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        fileOpen1 = "file1.pifz";
    }
    else 
    {
        fileOpen2 = "file2.pifz";
    }
    count++;
    printf("%s", line);
    printf("%s", fileOpen1);
    printf("%s", fileOpen2);
}
fclose(fr);
```

new test code (didn't work)

```
char *fileOpen1;
char *fileOpen2;
char *fileOpen3;
while(fgets(line, 50, fr) != NULL)
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        fileOpen1 = "file1.pifz";
    }
    else if(count == 0)
    {
        fileOpen2 = "file2.pifz";
    }
    else 
    {
        fileOpen3 = "file3.pifz";
    }
    count++;
    printf("%s", line);
    printf("%s", fileOpen1);
    printf("%s", fileOpen2);
    printf("%s", fileOpen3);
}
fclose(fr);
```

if i use the (new test code) it displays file1 and file3 twice instead of file1 > file2 > file3

```
    imageString(im, black, 15, 160,253 , thePrograms[0].progName); //needs to be file1
    imageString(im, black, 15, 160,303 , thePrograms[1].progName); //needs to be file2, but is file3
    imageString(im, black, 15, 160,353 , thePrograms[2].progName); //needs to be file3
```

Comment: um. `if (count=0) else if (count=0)`? "if this apple is red otherwise if this apple is red" is rather redundant... once a condition an if/else chain has matched, none of the other else conditions will even get executed.

Comment: Have you considered using an array to store the FILE * in and a simple loop?

Comment: You might also consider using a switch statement rather than a bunch of if ... then .... else statements.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(count==0)
{
    // You're here if count is 0
}
else if(count==0)
{
   // You're here if count isn't 0 and is 0
}
else
{
   // You're here if count isn't 0
}
```

You can't get into the first `else if`, because you've already established count isn't 0.

Answer (score 3):

Your second code wont work because you have the same condition twice (count == 0). Try changing the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You say if `count` equals 0 do something and then in the `if else` part you have `count == 0`. Replace it with `count == 1`.

```
if(count == 0)
{
    fileOpen1 = "file1.pifz";
}
else if(count == 0) // <-- make this  == 1
{
    fileOpen2 = "file2.pifz";
}
```